# Elasticsearch exporter index write operations metric

Tags: prometheus

I'm trying to create an alert that is triggered when some index has drop in receiving new data. Is it somehow possible? Does Elasticsearch exporter have any write operations metric?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Kibana Alerts](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.x/alerting-getting-started.html) to achieve that

From the other side will depend on which library are you using to ingest data into Elasticsearch. For example the [Javascript Client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/client-helpers.html) In its Bulk API helper can handle the errors, then you can send an alert if something happens with the server.

Comment: For alerts I'm going to use Prometheus operator. Alerts are not the problem. The question is about the metric. Is there some metric in the elasticsearch exporter that I can use to detect if some index has a drop in receiving data.

Comment: @passwd Did you get a way to get some metric in the elasticsearch exporter?